# How to isolate NodeJS server to only run tests from user input and avoid attacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

Given a `<textarea />`. It's assumed that the user will write a function there on assignment, but the fact is that he can write anything. Then the content from `<textarea />` is parsed as a string and sent to the backend to run some predefined unit tests.

On the server side NodeJS will parse the string and will create a function, like:

`"function(a, b) {return a+b}"`

will be converted to:

`const theParsedFunctionFromUserInput = new Function('a', 'b', 'return a+b')`

And then the server will run some unit test, like:

```
describe('The Unit Test', function(){
  it('should return a + b', function(){
    const isValid = theParsedFunctionFromUserInput(1, 2)
    assert.equal(isValid, 3);
  });
});
```

The question is how to avoid unwanted, undesirable code? For example, user can input something like

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.appendFile('somefile.js', 'unwanted content here');
```

or even worse :)

How to avoid these kinds of issues? I know that JS testing tools generally have CDN versions and I can simply run tests on client side, in `iframe` for example, but I'm looking for some general solution to be able to scale the solution and include other languages if needed.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: How do you know what the undesirable code would be?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Good question. Unfortunately, I don't know, but generally, it's something that will not modify the server, will not create any files, will not modify any global scope, will not get any data, etc.

Comment: There is no way to detect what might be bad code when given unknown code as input.  The best way would be to run it client-side where the client would only be harming themselves.  If you had to run it server-side, you would have to create a very locked down VM and run it in the VM so the worst the code could do is take down the VM (which you would just replace).  I also suppose you could run the code in a server-side browser engine with something like puppeteer which uses the chromium browser engine since the browser engine already has many safeguards.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, I guess I need a server-side solution to be able to scale it, for example, something like PHP I think I can't run on the client-side.. It seems I need a strong DevOps engineer for this))

Comment: I'm not sure how PHP is going to help you here as it can't run arbitrary code any safer than anything else.  And, FYI it will scale better if you run the code client-side so running it server-side isn't going to make it more scalable.  So, a couple of comments you made aren't making sense to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 I mean now I'm looking for a solution to test JS code, but in the future, there are plans to test for example PHP code or Python code, I don't think that I can run them on the client-side. This is why I want to make this on the server-side and scale the solution for multiple languages.

Comment: OK, you're going to need a locked down VM for any of those languages.